# UDP port 1433 (ms-sql-s service): NOT LISTENING

Tags: sql-server-2008

Screenshot of cmd console
[image]

Image of Main Error:

[image]

Image of Configuration manager where no server found:

[image]

I have try to search all solution for error 26 of sql server but no solution work for me.

I have check that server is running by going to services.msc and I have also checked through management configuration tool, but all get fail in my case. 
I have reinstall it to check any missing file in installation process. 
So at the end I have used PortQryUI.exe to find main reason where I get this message on my console

**UDP port 1433 (ms-sql-s service): NOT LISTENING**

I am attaching some screen shot for more clarification. And I have also follow all the steps given at stackoverflow.com for solving error 26 but no solution work for me so please don't close this question, may it have some other problem but sowing error 26.

Comment: You need to connect to `HETARAM-PC\SQLEXPRESS` not `HETARAM-PC:SQLEXPRESS`.

Comment: I have tried it earlier but it doesn't work

Comment: And in configuration tool it does not show any server name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I would like to thank you for you responses. Actually I have installed only management studio so I am facing this problem.
But earlier I have also installed only management studio when I am using visual studio 2010, but at that time it was working nicely. But when I have installed Visual Studio 2015 with SQL Server management studio 2012 after formatting my system, I have started facing this error.

**Why this problem**

Actually Microsoft have provided a facility in Visual studio that when we install it we will also get sql server installation with it so our management studio work nicely till Visual studio 2013. After that microsoft had removed this feature and now we need to install all the other file of SQL server with management studio.

**Solution**

We need to install SQL server files by our self. We can download them from Microsoft's site, like i have downloaded 2014 version from Microsoft's site.

[You can download SQL server 2014 express from here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=42299)

Answer (score 1):

**UDP** 1434 is the [SQL Server Browser Service](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087(v=sql.105).aspx) port. This service is disabled by default. This service is only needed when connecting to named SQL Server instances (or default instances listening on non-default ports) *from the network*. Local connections are able to discover named instances using the registry.

**TCP** port 1433 is the SQL Server listenning port for *default* instances. Named instances (like SQLEXPRESS) use a dynamic port by default.

The SQL Server Protocols team has some good *practical* troubleshooting articles for connectivity issues:

- [Steps to troubleshoot SQL connectivity issues](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2008/04/30/steps-to-troubleshoot-sql-connectivity-issues/)
- [How to Troubleshoot Connecting to the SQL Server Database Engine](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2102.how-to-troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine.aspx)
- [Solving Connectivity errors to SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4009936/solving-connectivity-errors-to-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

After a long time struggling with my SQL Server was just refusing to listen on 1433 despite following all advice online and searching extensively: My network was a public network. It took a long time before I got a thought that maybe SQL Server would have a check to not listen on a public network even if you try really hard to make it.

I don't know how my USB wifi home network was set to public in the first place, but I suppose I must have done that somehow. However I actually couldn't find this in any help or forums that I searched.